# Contar caracteres de um input sem incluir espaços entre palavras

Tags: php

```
$nome = $_POST['nome'];
$data = $_POST['data'];
$quantidade_car  = strlen(trim($nome));
var dump($quantidade_car);

echo "$nome <br> $data <br> $quantidade_car";

<form action="resultado-formulario.php" method="POST">

  <input name="nome" type="text" placeholder="Nome Completo">
  <input name="data" type="date">

  <button type="submit">Enviar</button>

</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dê um replace nos espaços:

```
$quantidade_car  = strlen(trim(str_replace(" ","",$nome)));
```

[função str_replace php](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.str-replace.php)

> Edit: contando valores por palavra

```
    $nome = $_POST['nome'];
    $data = $_POST['data'];

    $palavras = explode(" ", $nome);

    foreach ($palavras as $palavra){
        echo "$palavra <br> $data <br>". strlen(trim($palavra));
    }

    <form action="resultado-formulario.php" method="POST">

      <input name="nome" type="text" placeholder="Nome Completo">
      <input name="data" type="date">

      <button type="submit">Enviar</button>

    </form>
```

Comment: Opa, obrigado Alvaro Alves! perfeito!

Comment: caso tenha suprido a necessidade, por favor marque como resposta :D

Comment: Alvaro Alves, eu tenho mais uma dúvida, pode me ajudar ?

Comment: @JohnnySilva claro, estou à disposição

Comment: Obrigado, a sua resposta anterior foi ótima e me ajudou, porém eu tenho uma outra dúvida. Essa função está exibindo os cararcteres geral do input, porém eu gostaria de Separar a palavra inserida no input e contar os caracteres por palavra, não sei se conseguiu entender.

Comment: sim, entendi, um momento que já edito a resposta pra você :D

Comment: @JohnnySilva Editado, caso tenha suprido a necessidade, marque-a como resposta aceita

Comment: muito bom! mais uma vez agradeço a ajuda! Orbigado xD